# Creating a constructor for an array and populating it with a custom type

Tags: java, constructor, interface

I need to simulate a longword using bits where each index in an array contains a bit.
A new longword is then passed by input for comparison logic.
When I try to compare two longwords or set the longwords new value at i, I get The method set(int) in the type bit is not applicable for the arguments (bit)
This is my constructor:

```
private bit[] longArr;

    public longword() {
        int i;
        longArr = new bit[32];

        for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            longArr[i] = new bit();
        }
    }
```

AND Logic

```
 public longword and(longword other){
        bit[] newLongWord = new bit[32];
        int i,j;
        for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            newLongWord[i] = new bit();
        }
        for (j = 0; j< 32; j++){

            if(longArr[j] == other.longArr[j]){
                newLongWord[0].set(this.longArr[0].and(other.longArr[0]));

            }
            else if((longArr[j] != other.longArr[j])){
                newLongWord[0].set(this.longArr[0].and(other.longArr[0]));
            }
            else{
                newLongWord[0].set(this.longArr[0].and(other.longArr[0]));
            }
        }
        return other;
    }
```

I'm just trying to get to a point where I can run the code before implementing the correct logic.
Edit: my bit class

```
public class bit implements IBit {
    private int val; //provides class access to bit values

    public bit() {
        val = 0; //declare an initial bit value of 0
    }

    public void set(int val1) {
        if (val >= 0 && val <= 1) { //make sure the bit is in bounds of 0-1
            val = val1;
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Bit can only be 0 or 1"); //throw error when bit isnt 0 or 1
        }

    }

    public void toggle() {
        if (val == 0) {
            val = 1;
        }//switch bit value with opposite i.e 0 to 1
          
        else{
            val = 0;
        }

    }

    public void set() {
        val = 1; //sets default bit to 1 without parameter
    }

    public void clear() {
        val = 0; //sets bit to 0
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return val; //gets bit value
    }

    public bit and(bit two) {
        bit finished = new bit(); //new bit instance for first bit

        if (val == 0) {
            finished.set(0); //sees if bit1 is set to 0 for and logic
        }

        else {

            if (two.getValue() == 0) {

                finished.set(0);//sees if bit2 is set to 0
            }

            else {

                finished.set(1); //otherwise performs and on both bits creating a 1
            }

        }

        return finished;

    }

    public bit or(bit two) {
        bit finished = new bit(); //instance of bit
        if (val == 1){
            finished.set(1);
        } //if the first bit is 1, sets 1 return bit as 1
  
        else {
            if (finished.getValue() == 1) //if first bit is not 1 but new instance is 1, set return bit = 1
                finished.set(1);
            else
                finished.set(0);//else return bit = 0
        }

        return finished;
    }

    public bit xor(bit two) {
        bit finished = new bit(); //instance of bit
        if (val == 1) {
            if (two.getValue() == 0){//if second bit = 0, return bit is 1
                finished.set(1);
            }
            else{
                finished.set(0);//else return bit = 0
            }
        } 
        else {
            if (two.getValue() == 1){//If second bit =1 , return bit = 1
                finished.set(1);
            }
 
            else{
                finished.set(0);//else return bit = 0
            }
                
        }

        return finished;
    }

    public bit not() {

        if (val == 0) {//reversal of bit
            set(1);
        }

        else {
            set(0);
        }
        return this; // Returns the opposite of original bit val
    }

    public String toString() {
        String finalVal = Integer.toString(val);
        return finalVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is index always `0`? Should it be `newLongWord[j].set(this.longArr[j].and(other.longArr[j]));`?

Comment: It would help if you could also post your `bit` class.  Does it contain the methods `set` and `and`?  If so, what type arguments and return values do they have?

Comment: Apparently, `bit.and()` returns a `bit`, but `bit.set()` expects an `int` parameter. Create a `bit.set()` function that takes a `bit` object as parameter: `public void set(bit other) {...}`.

Comment: I edited in my bit class. As for the index, it is just a place holder right now until I can get this functioning.

Comment: It's not clear why you think you need a `bit` class (BTW, this should be `Bit` according to Java naming conventions).  Java already has all the methods you need to manipulate bits in binary values, via the `BitSet` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message sums it up: `and()` returns a `bit` but `set()` expects an `int`. Create a `set` function that takes a `bit`:

```
public void set(bit other) { set(other.val); }
```

Also, the logic in `longword.and()` can be simplified:

```
public longword and(longword other) {
    longword newLongWord = new longword();
    for (int j = 0; j < longArr.length; j++) {
        newLongWord.longArr[j].set(longArr[j].and(other.longArr[j]));
    }
    return newLongWord;
}
```

Comment: This is a homework problem and the professor is requiring that set(int value) is an int in the interface he gave us. Is there another way to work around this?

Comment: Sure, append `getValue()` to `and()` to pass the `int` from `getValue` to `set`: `newLongWord.longArr[j].set(longArr[j].and(other.longArr[j]).getValue());`

Comment: Or, write more than one `set` function in your class.  You should have one `set` function that takes an int, to satisfy your given interface, and you can have another `set` function that takes a `bit` for use in cases like these.  It's common in Java to have multiple functions with the same name but different arguments.  In fact, you already have two `set` functions (one that takes an int, and one that has no arguments), so this would actually involve writing a third one.

Comment: Ok so now I have created another set function the takes a bit in. I cannot seem to set the bit in the function equal to a 1 or 0 due to a type mismatch

Comment: @FrankFiumara I’d have to see the code. Maybe open another question.